# How weights interact with the loss function in H2O?

Tags: python, classification, h2o, loss-function

I am using H2O to perform a classification problem in a very imbalanced scenario. I decide to specify the instance weights, mapping all the 1's (positive and poorly represented class) with a high weight, and the 0's with a lower weight.

I would like to understand **how the weights interact with the loss function** and other components of the models (I am using AutoML) during training. I am not able to identify the core step in the source code.

Comment: AutoML uses various algorithms that have different methods of weights being used. You may want to review the algorithm implementations individually. GBM algo: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm.html#gbm-algorithm. GLM algo: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#h2o-implementation.  Note that generally the weights applied to the loss function are simply sum of loss*weight of the observation which equals cost/score

Comment: In this case, the weights are not so different w.r.t. class balancing, right?

Comment: Yes it is similar but you specify the weights